# Error While trying to get information SOAP from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, soap-client

I am trying to implement the Soap API in the application with the Node JS as a development server. I am using the following code. But I am getting an error message.

```
var soap = require('soap');
    var url = 'https://testwebservices.creditsafe.com/GlobalData/1.3/MainServiceBasic.svc/meta?wsdl';
    var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer("*****" + ":" + "*****").toString("base64");
    var args = { countries: 'US'  };
    soap.createClient(url, { wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth} }, function(err, client) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }else{


    client.FindCompanies(args ,function(err, result) 
                  {
                      if(err){
                    throw err
                    client.describe();  // here i am getting error message 
                      }else{
                        console.log(result); 

                      }
                  });
        }
    });
```

The Output what i am getting is here below. 
**cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'hr' server error **
[image]